# Is there any Cross-platform SQL editors that allow joins from different databases?

Tags: sql-server-2016, configuration

Initially tried dbeaver but after configuring it, I realized that you can't perform joins from different data bases.

Also tried TeamSQL which apparently does what I need but looks to be designed without privacy in mind (requires constant connection with internet).

```
Select a.Product, b.Product, a.ID, b.ID, c.Product, c.ID
FROM SQL_Server 1 a
LEFT JOIN Oracle b
ON a.ID = b.ID
LEFT JOIN SQL Server 2 (another location) c
ON a.ID = c.ID
```

Thank you for your time.

Comment: You could use DB2 and federate the two servers.  Then the query is local to the DB2 engine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the client side, there's [Quest Toad Data Point](https://www.quest.com/products/toad-data-point/), but I haven't used it.

I worked at Quest years ago when they sold a similar product, Toad for Data Analysts, and at the time, the problem was that people would wanna join big tables between multiple platforms - but do the filtering only after they found related rows. If you join a 1TB SQL Server table to a 1TB Oracle table, and you wanna do that join locally, you're going to need one seriously powerful desktop computer (server, really.)

On the server side, there's Microsoft SQL Server [Polybase](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/polybase/polybase-guide?view=sqlallproducts-allversions) and [Big Data Clusters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/big-data-cluster/big-data-cluster-overview?view=sqlallproducts-allversions), a database virtualization layer. In SQL Server 2019, they're supposed to be able to do what you're aiming for - but it's prerelease, and I haven't used that either.

Answer (score 4):

This seems more like something you'd set up in the database itself, than via an external tool.

Since this is [sql-server](/questions/tagged/sql-server), for instance, you can use [Linked Servers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/linked-servers/linked-servers-database-engine?view=sql-server-2017) to accomplish this.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response. Unfortunately, I don't have admin rights to perform that function.